# SVN: Error while updating filelist

Tags: svn

I got this strange error on SVN:

> Error while updating filelist (The path '/path/' appears to be part of a Subversion 1.7 or greater
>   working copy.  Please upgrade your Subversion client to use this
>   working copy.)

This sounds strange to me:

1. my svn server version is 1.6.11 (not 1.7)
2. my svn local client is 16.17

The command that I was trying to use is:

```
svn log -v
```

Any idea ?
I'm updating my client to 1.7 to see if it fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At some point you must have used SVN 1.7 to checkout the copy, or you obtained the working copy files from someone who did use SVN 1.7.

You will have to upgrade your client to SVN 1.7 to use the working copy -- it is not possible at this time to downgrade a working copy from 1.7 back down to 1.6.

Comment: This sound like the CLI client is conflicting with Netbeans plugin ... could it be ?

Comment: @Francesco yep, it could be it.